# Can't access local docker container when using VPN

Tags: docker, networking, vpn

I have a couple docker containers running on my local machine (pgadmin, jupyter notebooks etc) and have them mapped to various ports. I can happily navigate to localhost:10100 to get to the pgadmin web interface, for example. The issue is that when I connect to the work VPN I am unable to get to any locally running containers. I get an "ERR_CONNECTION_RESET" error on chrome.

With the VPN on I've tried:

- localhost:10100 (also tried 127.0.0.1)
- my-hostname:10100
- 192.168.0.X:10100 (the wifi interface address)
- 192.168.19.X:10100 (the VPN TUN interface address)

I can ping any of the above addresses and get a response and can successfully use them when the VPN is disabled. Using PulseVPN, Ubuntu 21.10, and fairly recent docker/docker-compose if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to run the containers with the host network by adding the flag:

> --network host

to the end of each command when you first start the containers.
And if that does not work, you can try it with:

> --network none

Comment: Giving the containers extended networking permissions isn't a bad idea. I'm not sure how  disabling all networking to the containers would help though

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that are a combination of issues that are causing problems. I haven't found a bullet proof solution yet but here are some breadcrumbs for someone else:

- The default docker network subnet was overlapping [with my work subnet](https://medium.com/codebrace/understanding-docker-networks-and-resolving-conflict-with-docker-subnet-ip-range-bfaad092a7ea).
- The VPN route was set to [have the lowest cost](https://netbeez.net/blog/linux-set-route-priorities/), therefor all traffic is being routed through it.
- Changing the default subnet resulted in the containers working, for around 5 minutes. Then the low cost routing was discovered and my traffic went through there instead.

My guess is that I have to fiddle with my network routing so that the docker networks are separated from the work VPN. It's been a decade since my CCNA so I can't remember how to do this off hand...